# Return Value in CakePHP Controller Function

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to create a recursive function in a controller that tests if a model has already been created. My model has a hasMany/belongsTo relationship with itself (so every model has a parent_id). Looks something like this:

**Site.php:**

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Children' => array(
        'className' => 'Site',
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
        'dependent' => true
    )
);

public $belongsTo = array(
    'Parent' => array(
        'className' => 'Site',
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
    )
);
```

Now every time a user visits a new Site, my controller goes through and creates new models for every new link found (link being any href in an `<a>` tag). This works fine, but I don't want it creating duplicate rows in my database for links that have already been added to this site, so what I'm doing is checking against the parent_id to see if the row already exists.

To do this, I need to keep checking the parent_id against every model until one of the models has no parent_id (it is null, this being the root domain). I'm using the following function inside of my Site Controller:

**SitesController.php:**

```
public function checkForExistingLink($site_id, $href) {
    $conditions = array(
        'Site.parent_id' => $site_id,
        'Site.url' => $href
    );

    if($this->Site->hasAny($conditions)) {
        debug('duplicate found');
        debug($href);
        debug($site_id);
        return $site_id;
    } else {
        $parent_site = $this->Site->findById($site_id);
        if($parent_site['Site']['parent_id'] == null) {
            debug('no duplicate found');
            debug($href);
            return 0;
        } else {
            debug('recall function');
            $this->checkForExistingLink($parent_site['Site']['parent_id'], $href);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my view method I am calling this function and storing the result to a variable:

```
$check_id = $this->checkForExistingLink($id, $href);
```

It appears to be parsing through the results fine (all of the debugs are being hit correctly), but when I debug the `$check_id` it is returning `null`. Can't seem to figure out why.

If anything is unclear, please ask and I'll try to explain the issue in more detail.

Comment: There's a couple of problems with this: 1.  Functions in the controller are supposed to correspond with an action -- a page on your site.  Therefore, writing a recursive function in the controller itself doesn't seem like a good idea to me.  Put it in a component instead.  2.  You can't normally, nor should you be, accessing functions in the Controller layer from the View.  Either put it in a helper instead, or since it looks like what you're trying to do requires the model, call it in the controller, then use $this->set('results', $results); to send the results to the view.

Comment: Lastly, I wanted to point out that you aren't returning the results of `$this->checkForExistingLink...` in that last line of your function before the closing braces, which is probably why you're ultimately coming up with null.